# How to show a Form on Click with some delay on Angular 7?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, animation

I have to change some angularJS code in Angular 7.

I've got a function that onClick shows me a new form bottom the principal one.

HTML

```
<img [hidden]=  "!skillsToDelete"
 (click)="showFormDelete(skill)" title="Delete"
 class="cross"
 src="../../../assets/icon/deletex.png">
```

TypeScript

```
    this.showCompDelete = false;

showFormDelete(skill) {
    this.showCompDelete = !this.showCompDelete;
    this.skillsToDelete.push(skill);
}
```

HTML DELETE COMPONENT

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 newForm" id="deleteSkill" *ngIf="showCompDelete">
```

CSS

```
.newForm{
    padding-left: 0;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: height ease 0.3s, opacity ease 0.3s, margin-bottom ease 0.3s, padding-top ease 0.3s
}
```

This transition doesn't work, I also tried -webkit but nothing happens.

This was the old one:

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 newForm" id="deleteSkill" style="display: block;">
```

JS

```
 $scope.showDeleteForm = function () {
        $('#formSkill').hide(300);
        $('#formExp').hide(300);
        $('#initSkills').hide(300);
        $('#certifiedSkill').hide(300);

        if($scope.skillToDelete.length){
            $('#deleteSkill').show(300);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.yesno').show(200);
            }, 300);
        }
        else{
            $('#deleteSkill').hide(300);
            $('.yesno').hide(0);
        }

    };
```

I would like to avoid css, and add something like "show(300)" in my TS, but if you have ideas also in css I would appreciate it.

Comment: sorry about the question but why do you want to avoid css? and what about angular 7 animation?

Comment: was thinking same. you should use angular animations. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLRP8Uhx-Qo maybe watch this.

Comment: I was just thinking about something like that "show(300)" but I don't know if I can, so if it's not possible CSS is ok.
I was looking for AngAnimation but it requires more time, oviously if there aren't other solution I will consider to use it @לבנימלכה

Comment: fine.. what this `this.skillsToDelete.push(skill);` (is it neccassety to answer)

Comment: do you want only delay or with also animation?

Comment: I have to delete skills from an user, so I have to push this "skills selected" in the other component that will delete them.

Comment: i would prefer animation, but just for starting a simple delay.

Comment: what do you thing about it? any suggestions? @לבנימלכה

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you ask for not using css you can use [`angular-animation`](https://angular.io/guide/animations)

[See working example code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-aniamtion?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Import `animation` for ts and use code as below

In `animate('1000ms 3000ms'` set the time for animation(in this example 1 second) and the time for delay(in this example 3 second)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import sdk from '@stackblitz/sdk';
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  animations: [
        trigger('showAnimation', [
            transition(':enter', [
                style({opacity: 0}),
                animate('1000ms 3000ms', style({opacity: 1}))
            ]),
            transition(':leave', [
                state('invisible', style({opacity: 0})),
                style({opacity: 1}),
                animate('1000ms 3000ms', style({opacity: 0}))
            ])
        ])
    ],
})
export class AppComponent  {
skillsToDelete=false;
showCompDelete=false;
animationState="leave";

showFormDelete(skill) {
    this.showCompDelete = !this.showCompDelete;
    this.animationState=this.animationState=="enter"?'leave':'enter';
    // this.skillsToDelete.push(skill);
}
}
```

In html use `*ngIf` and use code as below:

```
<img *ngIf=  "!skillsToDelete"
 (click)="showFormDelete(skill)" title="Delete"
 class="cross"
 src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4Ha4.jpg">

 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 newForm" id="deleteSkill" *ngIf="showCompDelete" [@showAnimation]="animationState"> 
 form with animation
 </div>
```